# Undefined identifier

Tags: c

I am working on a program in C which I am getting errors as identifiers opterr and optarg are undefined when opterr is set to 0. I noticed there is no #include  in that file. Can it be only possible reason ?

Errors

> error: identifier "opterr" is undefined

```
opterr = 0;
```

> error: identifier "optarg" is undefined

Comment: It is impossible to answer your Q conclusively unless you show the code.

Comment: Yes, its a possible reason.  To encourage more helpful responses, can you post a small example program and the exact errors compiling it generates please?

Answer (score 4):

Most likely you're missing:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <getopt.h>
```

which is where [getopt](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt) *et al* are defined.

Comment: #include <getopt.h> if you are using `optopt`, `optind`, etc

Answer (score 4):

optarg is defined in

`#include <getopt.h>`